# How do I fix the error "Deleting non-target project paths ["test-app/renderer/renderer.js%s"] is not allowed." when cleaning my project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I run lein clean, I get this error:

```
Deleting non-target project paths ["test-app/renderer/renderer.js%s"] is not allowed.
```

What makes a path a target project path? How do I make a path be a target project path? My project.clj looks like this:

```
(defproject tech.projectx/clients "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :cljsbuild {:builds {:renderer      {:source-paths ["src/renderer" "src/common"]
                                       :compiler     {:output-to     "app/renderer/renderer.js"
                                                      :output-dir    "app/renderer"
                                                      :asset-path    "renderer"
                                                      :main          configurator.core
                                                      :language-in   :ecmascript5
                                                      :optimizations :none}}
                       :main          {:source-paths ["src/main" "src/common"]
                                       :compiler     {:output-to     "app/main/main.js"
                                                      :output-dir    "app/main"
                                                      :asset-path    "main"
                                                      :main          tech.projectx.main
                                                      :target        :nodejs
                                                      :externs       ["node_modules/closurecompiler-externs/path.js"
                                                                      "node_modules/closurecompiler-externs/process.js"]
                                                      :optimizations :simple}} ; without this, the packed application doesn't work.
                       :renderer-test {:source-paths ["src/renderer" "src/common" "test/renderer"]
                                       :compiler     {:output-to            "test-app/renderer/renderer.js"
                                                      :output-dir           "test-app/renderer"
                                                      :asset-path           "renderer"
                                                      :main                 clientcommon.test-runner
                                                      :language-in          :ecmascript5
                                                      :optimizations        :none
                                                      :source-map           true
                                                      :source-map-timestamp true
                                                      :pretty-print         true}
                                       :figwheel     {:websocket-host "localhost"
                                                      :on-jsload      "clientcommon.test-runner/run-all-tests"}}
                       :test-app-main {:source-paths ["test/main" "src/main" "src/common"]
                                       :compiler     {:output-to            "test-app/main/main.js"
                                                      :output-dir           "test-app/main"
                                                      :asset-path           "main"
                                                      :main                 tech.projectx.test-app-main
                                                      :target               :nodejs
                                                      :externs              ["node_modules/closurecompiler-externs/path.js"
                                                                             "node_modules/closurecompiler-externs/process.js"]
                                                      :optimizations        :none
                                                      :source-map           true
                                                      :source-map-timestamp true
                                                      :pretty-print         true}}}}

  :sass {:source-paths ["src/renderer/assets"]
         :target-path  "app/renderer/assets"
         :source-map   true}

  :figwheel {:server-logfile "log/figwheel-logfile.log"
             :css-dirs       ["app/renderer/assets"]}


  :clean-targets [[:cljsbuild :builds :renderer :compiler :output-to]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :renderer :compiler :output-dir]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :main :compiler :output-to]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :main :compiler :output-dir]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :renderer-test :compiler :output-to]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :renderer-test :compiler :output-dir]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :test-app-main :compiler :output-to]
                  [:cljsbuild :builds :test-app-main :compiler :output-dir]
                  "dist"]

  :profiles {:dev  {:cljsbuild {:builds {:renderer {:compiler {:source-map           true
                                                               :source-map-timestamp true
                                                               :pretty-print         true}
                                                    :figwheel {:websocket-host "localhost"
                                                               :on-jsload      "configurator.core/mount-root"}}
                                         :main     {:compiler {:source-map           "app/main/main.js.map"
                                                               :source-map-timestamp true
                                                               :pretty-print         true}}}}}
             :prod {:cljsbuild {:builds {:renderer {:compiler {:optimizations   :simple
                                                               :closure-defines {goog.DEBUG false}}}
                                         :main     {:compiler {:optimizations   :simple
                                                               :closure-defines {goog.DEBUG false}}}}}}})
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a built in safety mechanism that protects you from accidentally deleting unwanted stuff (eg outside the project dir and such). If you'd like to still proceed with the cleanup, modify your project.clj like that:

```
:clean-targets ^{:protect false} [....]
```

For more details, look at the *sanity-check* and *protected-paths* functions in this source: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/clean.clj

Comment: I understand that I can disable the mechanism, it's in the error message. My question is why is in not considering those directories targets. Why is the output of renderer-test not ok to clean but renderer is?

Comment: @Pablo unfortunately I do not know of a feature of Leiningen that let's you debug its internal decisions (similar to what maven -X is in the java world)